# how to find max value across multiple columns and return value and the data of max value by grouping r

Tags: r, date, group-by, max, multiple-columns

I have a df called "Ak_total" with 3819 obj and 93 variable. 
I would like to calculate a max value for each column from 6:93 by group (Ak_total$Year).

The problem is that I would like get not only the max value of each column for each year (which is simple) but also find the day/date (Ak_total$Date) when the max value occur.

Example:

```
Year    Date    BetulaMAX
1998    1998-05-26  42
1999    1999-06-07  32
2000    2000-06-04  173
2001    2001-06-03  113
2002    2002-06-05  65

Year    Date    GrassMax
1998    1998-08-27  260
1999    1999-08-19  215
2000    2000-08-02  173
2001    2001-08-23  76
2002    2002-08-22  193
```

I did

```r
max value (Peak DATE)

max_all <- function(x) if(length(x))x==max(x)

Ak_max_date_Betula <- subset(Ak_total,!!ave(Betula, Year, FUN=max_all))
```

But I got the max and data only for one column (Betula).

Is it any possibility to do that for all columns in once?

Comment: how do you know that the max values for each column will appear on the same date?

Comment: I am almost pretty sure that the max values for each column will appear on different day. So that's why I would like to know not only how  much was the max value but also when it occurred. I can do it for one column but I do not know how to do for all in once. Is it possible at all? it would be much more convenient and much  most faster.